Drop Down List in Table Cell Depending on the Name of the Table Column
I have an *.jsp file.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
    <title>
          Drop Down List in Table Cell Depending on Name of Table Column
      </title>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <table id="Sample Table" border="1">

            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="element" items="${requestScope.tableColumnNames}">
                    <th>${element}</th>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="elements" items="${requestScope.tableRowValues}">
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach var="element" items="${elements}">
                        <td>${element}</td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>     
    </body>
</html>

The parameter tableColumnNames is an array:
String[] tableColumnNames = new String[]{"Table Column One","Table Column Two"};
The parameter tableRowValues is an array:
String[][] tableRowValues = new String[][]{{"Sample Value", "Yes / No"}};
I would like to have just for column two with the column name 'Table Column Two' the data displayed in a DropDown.
My assumption is to get from each cell the reference to the column and then use a if condition:
<c:forEach var="element" items="${elements}">
    <td>${element}
    <c:if <reference from cell to column (name)>="Table Column Two">
        <select>
            <option value="optionYes">
                Yes
            </option>
            <option value="OptionNo">
                No
            </option>
        </select>
    </c:if>
    </td>
</c:forEach>

I am not sure if this approach is correct.
Please adivse. Thanks much for your help.

You have to write some expression instead of <reference from cell to column (name)>="Table Column Two">. Do you know expression language?

I am not familiar with expression languange. Will do some research on this.

Are you familiar with html and javascript?

Well I learned it recently - just the very basics - and it was enough to find a solution.

Sleep a night to think about it and then the magic happens.
I found the following solution:
<c:forEach var="element" items="${elements}" varStatus="loop">
     <td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${requestScope.tableColumnNames[loop.index] == 'Table Column Two'}">
                <select>
                    <option value="optionYes">
                        Yes
                    </option>
                    <option value="OptionNo">
                        No
                    </option>
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                        ${element}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </c:when>    
            <c:otherwise>
                ${element}
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </td>
</c:forEach>

As desired in the column with the name 'Table Column Two' the data displayed in a DropDown.
